# What are hidden stack frames?

Tags: java, stack-trace

The stackwalker api has a setting to display **hidden and reflection frames**. 
What exactly are hidden frames? Running a hello world example shows no difference between these two settings for a trivial stack trace.

```
public static void getCallerClass() {
   StackWalker.getInstance().forEach(System.out::println); 
   StackWalker.getInstance(Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   getCallerClass();
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.Option.html#SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES

In the documentation it is only noted that hidden frames may be implementation specific. Can you please give me an example.

Comment: I'm guessing a hidden stack frame refers to a synthetic method.  Some times the compiler will "make up" new methods that it uses to implement some language features.  There's not a 100% match between the JVM and the language, so occasionally the compiler needs to make a "back door" to let it implement certain things that the JVM doesn't support.

Comment: @markspace are we talking about method used when utilizing streams or helper methods for generics?

Comment: Those as well, but I was thinking about anonymous and inner classes.